# TCPDF add line across page in header

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have created a custom header for my PDF created with TCPDF. Now I would like to add a blue line (about 2px width) that goes across the page at the bottom of the header but can't figure out how?

Answer (score 10):

I believe you do it like this:

```
$style = array('width' => 0.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(255, 0, 0));

$pdf->Line(5, 10, 80, 30, $style);
```

Here is the full example

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_012.phps

Comment: @PabliSerbo - Thanks for the examples I get it now. But how would you get the width of header to set the line width?

Comment: Thank you Serby. It works but for static pdf templates. If our pdf file has multiple pages with different orientations and pages sizes then we will have make condition wise Line styles. BTW Line method draws the line as given particular position/x-y coordinates. It is mixed/overlapped with text, image and other objects on the page. It does not set according to given block or available space. Tcpdf team should take care and improve these features.

Answer (score 9):

I found the easiest way to put line

```
$pdf->writeHTML("<hr>", true, false, false, false, '');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the page axis:

```
$pdf->Line(5, $pdf->y, $pdf->w - 5, $pdf->y);
```

However if you are trying to render a colored `<hr>` html tag you will need to adjust the `TCPDF::DrawColor` (this excerpt is from code that adds a graph bar to each row of a data report as per `$twidth` and `$lengthmm`):

```
$htmlbar = '<hr style="width:' . $lengthmm . 'mm;">';
$oldDrawColor = $pdf->DrawColor;
$pdf->setDrawColor(121, 161, 46);
$pdf->MultiCell($twidth,'2',$htmlbar,0,'L',$fill,1,'','',true,0,true,false,4,'T',false);
$pdf->DrawColor = $oldDrawColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Drawing a horizontal black line at the current position:

```
$style = ['width' => 0.2, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => [0, 0, 0]];
$this->pdf->SetLineStyle($style);

$this->pdf->Line(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, $this->pdf->getY(), $this->pdf->getPageWidth()-PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, $this->pdf->getY());
$this->pdf->Ln();
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is to get the x value for the second point.
This is how I do it:

```
$pageWidth    = $pdf->getPageWidth();   // Get total page width, without margins
$pageMargins  = $pdf->getMargins();     // Get all margins as array
$headerMargin = $pageMargins['header']; // Get the header margin
$px2          = $pageWidth - $headerMargin; // Compute x value for second point of line

$p1x   = $this->getX();
$p1y   = $this->getY();
$p2x   = $px2;
$p2y   = $p1y;  // Use same y for a straight line
$style = array();
$this->Line($p1x, $p1y, $p2x, $p2y, $style);
```

Links
TCPDF::getMargins()
http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ae9bd660bf5b5e00eea82f1168cc67b5b

TCPDF::getPageWidth()
http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a510ab21d6a373934bcd3bd4683704b7e

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Just add some HTML : )

```
$html ='<hr>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```